# How can I prove that my application is safe?

Tags: malware

I wanted to ask you, experienced programmers, a question that bothers me recently. I'm a second year student of the university of technology, where we spend a lot of time learning how to code. I found creating small but practical applications the best way to learn, and sometimes I would like to give them for free to someone else. And here the problem appears. If someone want to use it but is afraid that the app is not safe, I don't know any other way how to prove that it's not harmful but to show the source. It's not a big deal for me since those apps are not that big and complex, but I'm wondering if there is any way to show that the program is fully safe without sending the source code. It's basic stuff I guess, sorry if it sounds stupid an obvious.
Thanks.

Edit:
By "safe" I mean it's not a keylogger or anything like that.

Comment: I think you have to define 'safe' first.

Comment: How do you know that the compiler you used is safe? How do you know your Mail program is safe? Read this classic paper and learn that there's no way to know what's safe, even with source code: http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html

Comment: I think this is based on trust, we never install a program from a unknown vendor/person (most of the time). this is where antivirus programs, malware, rootkit detection programs comes to play.There is no way to prove your program is safe. safe in which means ? very hard to define

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I'll read this.

Comment: @Mike W The commonly accepted term which the original poster wanted to address is *security*, not safety. Safety in the software world is concerned with the protection of life and goods against harm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you strive hard to keep your app safe, when the underlying OS is vulnerable, it goes vain! So if you expect that trust, probably, if you have restrict your app to be in platforms, that you believe to be trustworthy.

For keyloggers you mean, show only virtual keyboard of your own app, donot use the system's default. Encrpyt evrything (data) you send from your app. Create a checksum value for you app, and when someone tampers it, make sure , your app recognises it and makes it unusable, till reinstalled. Have a pre installer to validate the platform, your app is being installed.

Never allow, external sources to access the app content. Secure your critical content, in a encrypted container.

may be the below link, provides some more insight!

http://www1.good.com/good-dynamics-platform/

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this is the same question as "how do I know *anything* is safe". Consumer appliances get recalled periodically, but we trust that they aren't deliberately designed to catch fire. If you aren't sure you trust it, you run it only when/where you can keep an eye on it and/or isolate it so it can't damage more than itself, or you throw it out.

If people don't trust the source of their code, they have two choices: Don't run it, or run it in a highly isolated environment.

The latter is a large part of what the Java Applet and Java security environment is about, but of course that does require that you trust whoever wrote the browser and/or set up the security environment to have done *that* successfully, and you have to trust that those don't have bugs that can be exploited.

If you're talking about *products*... There have been various practices published from time to time regarding how code should be written, and tested, for robustness. These days those may include "white hat" security attacks along with full code inspection and so on. If you can show that you're following these practices, it may reassure some folks who otherwise wouldn't trust you... but doing them with full rigor can be expensive, so part of this is knowing what your customers expect and/or will tolerate.

In the end, the real answer is that you need to start by writing trustworthy code, then know what the customer's concerns are and make sure you can meet their requirements either by delivering perfect code and/or by delivering above-average service and/or by being... no, I'm not going to take a cheap shot at that company this time.